# 3 Outcomes to a formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm a newbie on here and I'm struggling to do a formula on Excel,

I basically need If;

F7= Int 0 then J7=Int 1 
or 
F7=Rus 0 The J7=Rus 1 
or 
F7=Red 0 then J7=Red 1

F7 has data validation so I can choose from either Int 0 / Rus 0 / Red 0 and I need J7 to follow suit with either Int 1 /Rus 1 /Red 1 depending on what F7 is.

This all seemed so easy to explain in my head lol so I apologize

I can do it when there are 2 outcomes ie a true or false but because there are 3 I'm struggling.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
=LEFT(F7, 4) & MID(F7, 4,  100)+1
```

Comment: Don't you mean `MID(F7,4,1)` ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I mean everything starting from position 4, since it may be that the numbers are not single digits :)

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last sentence about 3 if() statements, try this:

```
=IF(Test1,result1,IF(Test2,result2,result3))
```